# Hangs up during the bootstrap process in openstack

Tags: openstack, timeout

I keep having this error for 2 days now.

sunbeam cluster bootstrap --accept-defaults
Timed out while waiting for model 'openstack' to be ready
Error: Timed out while waiting for model 'openstack' to be ready

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

only managed to install 5/23 then it hangs consistently. Please advise.
Deploying openstack control plane to kubernetes waiting for services to come online (5/23)

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial omits lots of stuff, you're probably hanging on some password prompt. You also might have hit limit for downloading containers from dockerhub, it might take a while to have it reset.

Other solution might be to use --edge version, but this openstack is in a such a rapid development cycle that i'm getting lost as to what's stable and what's not.

I have this little helper script (running it with sudo) for setting up the openstack/ubuntu user:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

apt install whois #for mkpasswd

USERNAME=ostack

PASSHASH=`mkpasswd -m sha-512 $USERNAME`
useradd -m -p $PASSHASH -s /bin/bash $USERNAME

echo "$USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/91-$USERNAME

runuser -l $USERNAME -c 'ssh-keygen -t rsa -q -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" -N ""'

cat /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown ostack:ostack /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys


chmod 700 /home/$USERNAME/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys


# Do this manually for the node you're on as $USER
# This is for proper entry in known_hosts
#ssh YOUR_REAL_FQDN.COM
```

I also have my little LiveStreams on YT where i tackle this stuff:
[LINK](https://www.youtube.com/@DCTekkie/streams)